# Using Redux's connect for various components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have three components which are embedded in each other, and they all to be hooked up to the reducers with the same actions.
It seems I have only found examples where in a certain container files where only one of the components is passed through the connect function.

How can I do this?

Here is my current code, although not sure if necessary:

```
    //need HelpMenu2 and HelpMenu3 to be passed through as well.
    export default connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(HelpMenu1);

Edit: As requested, here is the code:

class HelpMenu extends Component{
    render(){
        var me=this;
        var api ="https://api.someapi.com/";
        return(
            <ul>
                <div >Click here to test</div><br/>
                {this.state.allTopics.map(function (helpTopics, key) {
                    return (
                        <ul key={key}>
                            <li>

                                <div onClick={()=>me.props.fetchHelpTopics(api)}>
                                    {helpTopics.id}
                                    </div>
                                <ul>
                                    {helpTopics.isExpanded ? <SubMenu2 helpTopics={helpTopics}  isLastExpanded={false}/> : null}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class SubMenu extends Component{

    render(){
        var me =this;
        var api ="https://api.someapi.com/";
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.helpTopics.subtopics.map(function (helpSubtopics, key) {
                    return (
                        <ul key={key}>
                            <li>
                                <div onClick={()=>me.props.fetchHelpTopics(api)}>
                                    {helpSubtopics.id}</div>
                                {helpSubtopics.isExpanded ? <LastSubMenu helpSubtopics={ helpSubtopics}/> : null}
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class LastSubMenu extends Component{

    render(){
        var me=this;
        var api ="https://api.someapi.com/";
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.helpSubtopics.subtopics
                    .map(function (helpSubSubtopics, key) {
                        return (
                            <ul key={key}>
                                <li>
                                    <div
                                        onClick={me.onTopicClick.bind(me, helpSubSubtopics)}>
                                            <div onClick={()=>me.props.fetchHelpTopics(api)}>
                                        {helpSubSubtopics.title}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        );
                    })}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

The events would happen where there is the onClick on the tag.

Edit: my connect code:

```
export default connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(HelpMenu);
```

How would I make multiple calls for it? From my understanding, you can only use `export default` once per file,
so I did this:

```
export default connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(HelpMenu);
connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(SubMenu2);
connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(LastSubMenu);
```

Which doesn't work.

Comment: can you show how your components are embedded in each other ?

Comment: It's not exactly pretty... It's basically one list embeded in the other, but I'll add an edit with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call connect again with the other components.

You need to export the returned value from each method call separately.
in ES6 that can look like this. (you might need to search for what syntax works with your js setup)

`export const first = connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(HelpMenu);
export const second = connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(SubMenu2);
export const third = connect( mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(LastSubMenu);`

Then access them separately in the component that displays them.

Comment: tried it. Doesn't work. It simply ignores the other calls.

Comment: You can call connect multiple times. You probably need to show more code to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Maybe I just have some kind of misunderstanding and I am still quite new at this. I added the code which I tried and why I tried it that way, so sorry if I am way off. But how could I do this to make it work?

Comment: no problem, see my edited answer. It was just a javascript syntax issue. Mozilla has some good resources for reading up on syntax.

I also strongly recommend Dan Abramov's tutorial to help you get your head around how it works with redux: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux He created redux so he knows what he's talking about :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind help and advice.
I hate to be the kinda person that keeps asking for more, but it still isn't working for me, because all three Components are embeded in each other (LastMenu is in SubMenu2 which is in HelpMenu), how could I access them separately? Ideally what I need is that only HelpMenu be the one called in the component

Comment: Update: I'n an idiot, all I had to do was use the consts instead of the components themselves :)